# Angular - Bootstrap 5 "utilities" not compiled

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-5, utilities

I've upgraded my angular app to use the bootstrap 5 styles. Since bootstrap 5 removed many utilities like `cursor-pointer`, I now have to define the utilities I want to use myself. I've tried to use the api [as described in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#add-utilities), but without success. The so called utilities I write never end up in the resulting css file.

In the **styles.scss** I have written the following utility according to the docs:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge(
    $utilities,
    (
        "cursor": (
            property: cursor,
            class: cursor,
            // responsive: true,
            // values: auto pointer grab
            values: (
                pointer: pointer,
                grab: grab
            )
        )
    )
);
```

So this should be compiled to style rules like `.cursor-pointer { cursor: pointer }` and `.cursor-grab { cursor: grab }`. But when I look in the resulting **styles.css**, the rules I defined are nowhere to be found.

I've published a [repository here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-draggable-listview).

- [SCSS file containing my utility](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-draggable-listview/blob/master/projects/ng-draggable-listview-demo/src/styles.scss)
- [Place where I'm using the utility](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-draggable-listview/blob/master/projects/ng-draggable-listview-demo/src/app/app.component.html#L2)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mzexcm?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

- Instead of importing the `bootstrap.scss` through `angular.json`, import it from `styles.scss`:

angular.json

```
{
  ...,
  "projects": {
    "ng-draggable-listview-demo": {
      ...,
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...,
          "options": {
            ...,
            "styles": [
              //"node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "projects/ng-draggable-listview-demo/src/styles.scss"
            ]
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

src/styles.scss

```
$utilities: () !default;

$utilities: map-merge(
    $utilities,
    (
        "cursor": (
            property: cursor,
            class: cursor,
            values: (
                pointer: pointer,
                grab: grab
            )
        )
    )
);

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Now you can use both the bootstrap utilities (eg. float-end) and your own utilities (eg. cursor-grab):

```
<body>
  <ul class="list-group cursor-grab">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
      <span class="float-end">{{ item }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```